# C# MVC3 authorize current logged in user against active directory group

Tags: .net

I've got a MVC3 front end to an application that I'm working on.  I can block or grant access to an active directory group successfully by using [Authorize(Roles=@"MYDOMAIN\MYGROUP")].  Before I authenticate I can pull and display the domain\username on the webpage so I know it's seeing the user and fully expected to see this information used to authenticate the user.  However, unexpectedly I'm getting a logon prompt which requires me to re-authenticate the user I'm currently logged in with. Once I re-authenticate the user it then works fine on the site.  Ultimately I do want it to ask for authentication if it cannot determine who is logged in.  I'm sure someone has asked this question before but I'm not finding anything on it; I guess I'm not sure what the terminology is to search for exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually doesn't matter what application you are targeting, its related to Windows Authentication, so you need to try check configs.

Refer
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94612/Windows-Authentication

For more details
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98950/ASP-NET-authentication-and-authorization